# Email notification for messaging

Tags: ektron

I am using 8.0.1 SP1.

I have not been able to find a definitive answer for this so far. Does the messaging server control have an option for notifying the user via email that a message has been sent to them?  Email is set up for the site and working. In my site, I have community notifications set to email in my profile. I have ek_EnableMessageBoardEmail set to true in web.config. I do realize that there is a difference between message board and the messaging server control but I am trying everything. Is this possible without coding the functionality? If not, can someone point me toward some starter code?

I also posted this question at http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=41480

Thanks.

Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible.  The Ektron Messaging control can only send internal messages within the CMS to other users.  The server control produces markup that looks a bit like it might be email but it is not.

The Messaging control does have the ability to send an email to a community group but not individual users.

See Ektron's documentation [here](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v801/mobile_help/advanced/content/Community_Management/Community_Management_sc_messaging.htm).

You will have to code your own custom solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  This is what we eventually found out also.  In a way it worked out for us.  Having some limitations kept the client from trying to turn the site into a Constant Contact clone.